# Drop data frame rows if NA for certain variables referred to by name in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I would like to drop entire rows from a data frame if they have all NAs but for only certain subset of columns (which are named in a sequence as well as start with "X").

This is different than other SO answers that I found from what I can tell since I cannot refer to each column manually by name (too many variables) and do not only want to drop the rows if they are completely NA (rather if some variables are completely NA).

So turn sample data:

```
data1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1, NA, 4), c(4,6,7), c(1, NA, NA), c(4, 8, NA))) 
colnames(data1) <- c("Z","X1","X2")
data1
 Z X1 X2
1 1  2  3
2 1 NA  4
3 4  6  7
4 1 NA NA
5 4  8 NA
```

into:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
3  4  6  7
4  4  8 NA
```

I.e. drop the row if both X1 and X2 (all of the X sequence) are NA.

In this example there are only two variables(X1:X2)for ease but in reality I have closer to 100 of this sequence and many other important variables that may or may not be NA. I would prefer to do so in dplyr with filter but other solutions would be appreciated as well.

I feel like:

```
data2 %>% filter(!is.na(all(X1:X2)))
```

or something similar is close but R does not like the sequence reference to X1:X2  within filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rowSums + select + starts_with + filter`:

```
data1 %>% 
    filter(rowSums(!is.na(select(., starts_with("X")))) != 0)

#  Z X1 X2
#1 1  2  3
#2 1 NA  4
#3 4  6  7
#4 4  8 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution using `apply` would be:

```
drop <- which(apply(data1[,startsWith(colnames(data1), "X")], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
data1[-drop,]
#  Z X1 X2
#1 1  2  3
#2 1 NA  4
#3 4  6  7
#5 4  8 NA
```

---

Another option using `rowSums`:

```
drop <- which(rowSums(is.na(data1[,c("X1","X2")]))>=2)
data1[-drop]
```